# Display ANSI colours with curl?

Tags: colors, curl, ansi

I'm currently trying to `curl` some raw text and have it displayed with interpreted ANSI colours in the Terminal.

Currently, when I run `curl http://example.com/test.txt` (not the actual URL), it simply returns:

```
\033[0;31mTEST\033[0m
```

This is not what I am looking for; what I expected to be returned is what I see when I run `echo -e "\033[0;31mTEST\033[0m"`, which returns `TEST`, coloured in red.

My question is: is there a way of making `curl` interpret ANSI colour codes in order to have the colours properly displayed in the Terminal as you would expect when using `echo -e`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why use `curl` here? I mean, it's a tool for the HTTP protocol, and you're dealing with ANSI escape codes for the terminal. I feel like I'm missing a connection here.

Comment: @Haxiel Interestingly enough, I'm trying to add a sort of easter egg to a poster at my college, where `echo -e "$(curl -s http://example.com/test.txt)"` is in small print, and if they find the message they win a prize.

Comment: Curl 7.66.0 and later no longer allow raw text by default. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but using command substitution seems to work fine (even if it is a bit bulky):

```
echo -e "$(curl -s http://example.com/test.txt)"
```

Hopefully that's helpful for people in the future. Note that you can use `curl -sL` if you are dealing with a shortened URL.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer: `curl --http0.9 example.com/test.txt`

As of curl 7.66.0, raw text is rejected by default. Adding **--http0.9** fixes the problem. Here is an example, using netcat to fake the webserver:

```bsh
echo $'\e[0;31mTEST\e[0m' | nc -l -p 8080 -q0 &

curl --http0.9 localhost:8080
```

### Another answer: `nc example.com 80`

Netcat can also grab text from a webserver. However, it doesn't speak HTTP, so it is a little trickier:

```bsh
printf "GET / HTTP/1.0\nHost: example.com\n\n" | nc -C example.com 80
```

Comment: Here's a demo you can use online.
https://copy.sh/v86/?profile=archlinux&c=echo%20%24'e%5B0%3B31mTESTe%5B0m'%20%7C%20nc%20-l%20-p%208080%26curl%20localhost%3A8080

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like you forgot the backslashes in `$'\e`. It works fine when if you add those (and use wget since curl no longer accepts raw text over a socket). Here's the link: [copy.sh](https://copy.sh/v86/?profile=archlinux&c=echo%20%24%27\e[0%3B31mTEST\e[0m%27%20|%20nc%20-l%20-p%208080%26wget%20-q%20-T1%20-O-%20localhost%3A8080)

Comment: https://copy.sh/v86/?profile=archlinux&c=echo%20%24%27%5Ce%5B0%3B31mTEST%5Ce%5B0m%27%20|%20nc%20-l%20-p%208080%26nc%20localhost%208080

Comment: Thanks, @Anonymous, that's a good suggestion. I've updated my answer to use netcat.